# matlab: close the gui if the user presses the close button

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I made a GUI that gets 2 elements: files (list of files) and options (I will explain later).

there is a function that calls the function below:

```
// asume that this is my 'options'
options{1} = {'Treatment', 't1', 't2'};
options{2} = {'Tree', '1', '2'};
options{3} = {'Replica', 'r1', 'r2', 'r3'};

// asume that this is my 'files' (may be more than 2 images
files{1} = 'C:\Documents and Settings\erezalon\Desktop\gib_proj_02.10.12\fina3_32bit\IMG_4640.JPG';
files{2} = 'C:\Documents and Settings\erezalon\Desktop\gib_proj_02.10.12\fina3_32bit\grapes03.jpg';


mydata = mainGUI(options, files).

// here I want to check 'mydata'. if it is equal to zero or not.
```

for each image, the GUI is created in the function 'mainGUI' (but each time, one GUI is showed till the user presses 'next').

I want to do the next thing:

if the user presses the close button in the GUI, I want to stop the displaying of the other GUI-s and set 'data = 0'. then, I will check what is the returned element ('mydata') and if it's equal to 0, I will know that the user closed the GUI and I will act as needed.

I tried to do this by the 'cmdClose_Callback' but it doesn't work.

assume that 'files' = two images, so this is the GUI of the first image.

I press the close button:

[image]

and got the GUI of the second image despite of closing the GUI of the first image.

[image]

I want that when I close the GUI, the other GUI-s don't appear.

this is my code:

```
function  data = mainGUI(options, files)
 %# current options
 j = 1;
 ops = cellfun(@(c) c(1), options, 'Uniform',false);
 data{j} =  [ops{1:length(ops)}];
 j = j + 1;


 options = cellfun(@(c) c(2:1:end), options, 'Uniform',false);
 clear ops;
 ops = cellfun(@(c) c(1), options, 'Uniform',false);
 opts =  [ops{1:length(ops)}];

%# create main figure, with plot and options button
hFig = figure('Name','window 1','Visible','Off');
a = 1
callback

%# options button callback function
function callback(o,e)
    a = 2
    %# save current options (sharing data between the two GUIs)
    setappdata(hFig, 'opts',opts);

    %# display options dialog and wait for it

    for k=1: length(files)

            hOptsGUI = secondaryGUI(hFig, options, k, length(files));

            img = imread(files{k});  %# Read the data from image file data
            hAxes = axes('Parent',hOptsGUI,'Units','pixels','Position',[362 242 424 359]);  %#   so the position is easy to define
            image(img,'Parent',hAxes);  %# Plot the image
            set(hAxes,'Visible','off');          %# Turn the axes visibility off

            a = 3

            waitfor(hOptsGUI);

            a = 4
            %# get new options, and update plot accordingly
            opts = getappdata(hFig, 'opts');
             data{j} = opts;
             j = j + 1;
    end
end

end

function hFig = secondaryGUI(hParentFig, options, k, num_files)
%# create figure

a = 5


hFig = figure('Name','Step 3 of 4: Choose data for each image','Menubar','none', 'Resize','off', ...
    'WindowStyle','modal', 'Position',[300 300 1150 600], 'CloseRequestFcn',@cmdClose_Callback);
set(gcf,'NumberTitle','off')
movegui(hFig, 'center');



options = cellfun(@(c) c(end:-1:1), options, 'Uniform',false);
num = length(options);

%# get saved settings
selected = getappdata(hParentFig, 'opts');
a = 6
%# top/bottom panels
hPanBot = uipanel('Parent',hFig, 'BorderType','none', ...
    'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0 0.0 1 0.2]);

hPanTop = uipanel('Parent',hFig, 'BorderType','none', ...
    'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0 0.2 1 0.2]);



%# buttongroups in top panel
hBtnGrp = zeros(1,num);
width = 1/num;
for i=1:num
    %# create button group
    hBtnGrp(i) = uibuttongroup('Parent',hPanTop, ...
        'Units','normalized', 'Position',[(i-1)*width 0 width 1]);
    %# populate it with radio buttons
    height = 1./numel(options{i});
    for j=1:numel(options{i})
        h = uicontrol('Parent',hBtnGrp(i), 'Style','Radio', ...
            'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0.05 (j-1)*height 0.9 height], ...
            'String',options{i}{j});
        %# set initially selected values
        if strcmp(selected{i},options{i}{j})
            set(hBtnGrp(i), 'SelectedObject',h)
        end
    end
end

if k ~= num_files
%# save button in bottom panel
uicontrol('Parent',hPanBot, 'Style','pushbutton', ...
    'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0.3 0.2 0.4 0.2], ...
    'String','next', 'Callback',@callback);

else
    uicontrol('Parent',hPanBot, 'Style','pushbutton', ...
    'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0.3 0.2 0.4 0.2], ...
    'String','start', 'Callback',@callback);
end


%# save button callback function
function callback(o,e)
    a = 7
    %# get selected values
    hObjs = get(hBtnGrp(:), 'SelectedObject');
    vals = get(cell2mat(hObjs),{'String'});

    %# update settings
    setappdata(hParentFig, 'opts',vals);


    close(hFig)
    a = 8
end

 function cmdClose_Callback(hObject,varargin)
    disp(['Close Request coming from: ',get(hObject,'Type')]);
    a = 9

    %do cleanup here
    delete(hFig);
    a = 10

 end
end
```

if 'files' has two images, I push the 'next' button for the first figure, and in the second figure I close, I get:

```
a = 1
a = 2
a = 5
a = 6
a = 3
a = 7
Close Request coming from: figure
a = 9
a = 10
a = 8
a = 4
a = 5
a = 6
a = 3
Close Request coming from: figure
a = 9
a = 10
a = 4
```

above the line: hOptsGUI = secondaryGUI(hFig, options, k, length(files));
I tried to put some lines. In order to testthe lines, I print a fit message:

```
if (ishandle(hFig))
     disp('exists');
else disp('was closed');
end;
```

but it doesn't work :/

**for each GUI that the user will close, the next callback will called:**

```
function callback(o,e)

    %# get selected values
    hObjs = get(hBtnGrp(:), 'SelectedObject');
    vals = get(cell2mat(hObjs),{'String'});

    %# update settings
    setappdata(hParentFig, 'opts',vals);

    %# close options dialog
    close(hFig)

end
```

**so I just need to know in the next 'for loop' if this callback was called:**

```
for k=1: length(files)
```

**how can I do that?**

Comment: Does `delete(hFig)` help you at all?

Comment: no, it doesn't :/ I tried to put delete(hfig) below to the line 'callback' in mainGUI function. thank you for your trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I succeeded!

I used setappdata and getappdata in order to know if the second callback was called.

@Derek, **Derek, thank you very much for your help and that you spent a lot of time for me!**

```
function  data = mainGUI(options, files)
 %# current options
 j = 1;
 ops = cellfun(@(c) c(1), options, 'Uniform',false);
 data{j} =  [ops{1:length(ops)}];
 j = j + 1;


 options = cellfun(@(c) c(2:1:end), options, 'Uniform',false);
 clear ops;
 ops = cellfun(@(c) c(1), options, 'Uniform',false);
 opts =  [ops{1:length(ops)}];

%# create main figure, with plot and options button
hFig = figure('Name','window 1','Visible','Off');
callback


%# options button callback function
function callback(o,e)
    %# save current options (sharing data between the two GUIs)
    setappdata(hFig, 'opts',opts);

    %# display options dialog and wait for it

    for k=1: length(files)
            hOptsGUI = secondaryGUI(hFig, options, k, length(files));

            img = imread(files{k});  %# Read the data from your image file
            hAxes = axes('Parent',hOptsGUI,'Units','pixels','Position',[362 242 424 359]);  %#   so the position is easy to define
            image(img,'Parent',hAxes);  %# Plot the image
            set(hAxes,'Visible','off');          %# Turn the axes visibility off

            out = 'FALSE';
            setappdata(hFig,'some_var',out);
            % show the images
            %%Im = imread(files{k});
            %%AxesH = axes('Units', 'pixels', 'position', [0.5, 10, 400, 260], 'Visible', 'off');
            %%image('Parent', AxesH, 'CData', Im); %# add other property-value pairs as needed

            waitfor(hOptsGUI);

            some_other_var = getappdata(hFig,'some_var');

            if (strcmp(some_other_var, 'OK') == 1)
                 %# get new options, and update plot accordingly
                opts = getappdata(hFig, 'opts');
                data{j} = opts;
                j = j + 1;
            else
                k = length(files);
                data = 0;
                return;
            end;
    end
end
end

function hFig = secondaryGUI(hParentFig, options, k, num_files)
%# create figure


hFig = figure('Name','Step 3 of 4: Choose data for each image','Menubar','none', 'Resize','off', ...
    'WindowStyle','modal', 'Position',[300 300 1150 600]);
set(gcf,'NumberTitle','off')
movegui(hFig, 'center');



options = cellfun(@(c) c(end:-1:1), options, 'Uniform',false);
num = length(options);

%# get saved settings
selected = getappdata(hParentFig, 'opts');

%# top/bottom panels
hPanBot = uipanel('Parent',hFig, 'BorderType','none', ...
    'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0 0.0 1 0.2]);

hPanTop = uipanel('Parent',hFig, 'BorderType','none', ...
    'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0 0.2 1 0.2]);



%# buttongroups in top panel
hBtnGrp = zeros(1,num);
width = 1/num;
for i=1:num
    %# create button group
    hBtnGrp(i) = uibuttongroup('Parent',hPanTop, ...
        'Units','normalized', 'Position',[(i-1)*width 0 width 1]);
    %# populate it with radio buttons
    height = 1./numel(options{i});
    for j=1:numel(options{i})
        h = uicontrol('Parent',hBtnGrp(i), 'Style','Radio', ...
            'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0.05 (j-1)*height 0.9 height], ...
            'String',options{i}{j});
        %# set initially selected values
        if strcmp(selected{i},options{i}{j})
            set(hBtnGrp(i), 'SelectedObject',h)
        end
    end
end

if k ~= num_files
%# save button in bottom panel
uicontrol('Parent',hPanBot, 'Style','pushbutton', ...
    'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0.3 0.2 0.4 0.2], ...
    'String','next', 'Callback',@callback);
else
    uicontrol('Parent',hPanBot, 'Style','pushbutton', ...
    'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0.3 0.2 0.4 0.2], ...
    'String','start', 'Callback',@callback);
end
%# save button callback function
function callback(o,e)
    out = 'OK';
    setappdata(hParentFig,'some_var',out);
    %# get selected values
    hObjs = get(hBtnGrp(:), 'SelectedObject');
    vals = get(cell2mat(hObjs),{'String'});

    %# update settings
    setappdata(hParentFig, 'opts',vals);

    %# close options dialog
    close(hFig)
end

function cmdClose_Callback(hObject,varargin)  
    %do cleanup here
    delete(hFig);
end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Just check to see if `hFig1` is a valid handle before you create the second figure.

```
if ishandle(hFig1)
    hFig2 = figure(...)
else
    return;      % do something else
end
```

Repeat as needed.

---

```
function data = mainGUI(options, files)
    % ...
    % create main figure, with plot and options button
    hFig = figure('Name','window 1','Visible','Off');

    complete = callback;
    if complete == 1
        data = data;  
    else 
        data = 0;
    end

% options button callback function
function complete = callback(o,e)
    %save current options (sharing data between the two GUIs)
    setappdata(hFig, 'opts',opts);

    % display options dialog and wait for it
    complete = 0;
    for k = 1 : length(files)
        hOptsGUI = secondaryGUI(hFig, options, k, length(files));
        % ...
    end
    % we reached the end of the loop!
    complete = 1;
end
```

Comment: are you sure? I think it's not be a valid handle anyway, because the handle can be closed by the 'close' button or when the user presses the 'next' button.

Comment: @AlonShmiel Not sure if I understand what you are trying to do. See updated code.

Comment: @AlonShmiel If figure 1 is closed by the user, then we don't create figure 2. Is this what you want?

Comment: yes, I am trying what you suggested and I will let you no if it works or doesn't. thank you!

Comment: I think I don't know where to check it..
I checked it in the 'for loop' of 'callback', below the line:  hOptsGUI = secondaryGUI(hFig, options, k, length(files));

Comment: I think you probably want to check it before that line, i.e. don't call that line if the main figure is closed.

Comment: @AlonShmiel OK, how does the function `callback` know about the first figure handle, `hFig`? That is the handle of the first window, right? I don't see how `hFig` is defined in the second function.

Comment: @AlonShmiel Are you creating a new figure for the second step or are you reusing the existing figure? If a figure is closed, it's handle will become invalid. There is no getting around that.

Comment: I think you are right. I have two figures. the first figure is invisible, and the second figure is reused again and again (if you have a time, see my updating topic). thank you very much!!! :]

Comment: @AlonShmiel And if any of the "second figures" are closed, you don't want to make the first figure visible?

Comment: no, I want that if the "second figures" are closed, all the figures will be closed and the returned element ('data') of this function will be equal to 0. thank you for your help!

Comment: @AlonShmiel What if you set a flag after the for loop in the `callback` function? So, if we reach the end of the for loop, we can assume that the user completed all of the tasks. Thus, we set a flag and return this flag to the `mainGUI` function. The `mainGUI` function will then return the `data` or 0. Make some sense?

Comment: I am updating my topic again. I put a=1, a=2, ... a=10 in the code in order to know whats happens.

Comment: @AlonShmiel Have a look at my updated answer. Would this work?

Comment: it doesn't work.. can you please copy my code to your matlab and run it? I will explain again..

Comment: I am going to sleep. the time here is 6:45 in the morning and I didn't sleep all the night because I tried to fix this problem. thank you again and again! Alon.

Comment: I succeed something: I have a parameter. if it's equal to "FALSE" I have to close all the figures. now I am trying to close all. I will update you.. thank you very much for everything!

Answer (score 0):

There is no call to close the figure from the first GUI.

You may want to add a call `close(hFig)` to the end of the `mainGUI` function.